# C++ saying class is an unknown override specifier?

Tags: c++

I have two classes that I'm trying to get to communicate with each other but c++ says that the class name is an unknown override specifier.
This is what it looks like

```
#include "B.h"

class B;

class A
{
private:
    B* ptrB;
public:
    void setB(B* ptr) { ptrB = ptr; }
};
```

```
#include "A.h"

class B
{
private:
    A m;
public:
    bus()
    {
        m.setB(this);
    }
};
```

the error I'm getting is

```
B.h: error C3646:'A': unknown override specifier
B.h: error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

Comment: `class B` is missing a semicolon. Voting to close as typo.

Comment: edit: I've added the semicolon

Comment: You have mutually recursive includes, that's usually a bad idea. Remove `#include "B.h"` from A.h. In the code you've posted you don't need it.

Comment: @john i made a mistake in the example could you check again please

Comment: @JerSci I don't see anything to make me change the advice I gave in the previous comment. But I do wonder if the posted code reflects the code you are actually working with.

Comment: @john how will class B know about class  A if i remove the header?

Comment: @JerSci No you've got it the wrong way round. Remove `#include "B.h"` from A.h. Leave `#include "A.h"` where it is.

Comment: @john this is the error i'm getting now "use of undefined type 'Bus' "

Comment: and "'A::A': cannot define a compiler-generated special member function (must be declared in the class first)"

Comment: I'm using the class B in A, I've just simplified it so the example is easy to explain

Comment: @JerSci What is `bus` (in your opinion).

Comment: @JerSci I was worried that was the case. These things are tricky, you should post the real code. Otherwise you're just going to get answers that work for the posted code, but not for your real code.

Comment: @john it's way too big to post. Do you have any other ideas of what i could do instead to connect A and B?

Comment: In general the way to deal with mutually dependent classes like `A` and `B` is to use forward declarations and to carefully order the code so that everything is defined before it is needed. The may involve splitting a class into pieces instead of defining all of it all at once. But it's hard to generalise, the details of your actual code are what matter.

Comment: It also might involve combining your two header files files into one. `A` and `B` could be so intertwined that it's not practical to separate them.

Answer (score 1):

Semicolon (;) is missing after `class B` forward declaration.